# Optimization (Calculus 1)

Tags: calculus, optimization

[image]A triangle is formed by the coordinate axes and a line through the point (2, 5) as 
       shown in the figure below.  Determine the slope of this line if the area of the triangle 
       is to be a minimum.

My attempt: I used the slope formula as well as the area formula for a triangle. Substituted x for base and y for height. I know I'm supposed to substitute x and y in terms of m. Then derive and find the absolute minimum for m.

Number 11.

Comment: I don't think we can help without seeing the figure.

Comment: @GregoryGrant: presumably the hypotenuse through $(2,5)$ has negative slope and it is simple to state the intersections with the axes in terms of the slope, and thus the area, which can be maximised for a particular slope.

Comment: Dhondup Tenzing: what did you find for the intersections with the axes in terms of $m$? Would would the areas then be in terms of $m$?

Comment: @Henry That's were I'm stuck at.

Answer (score 0):

The area of a right triangle is given by $A=ab/2$, where in this case a and b are the lengths of the legs, which also happen to be the coordinates of the intercepts.  The intercept equation of a line is useful here and is given by

$$\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}=1$$
Since the point goes through (2,5), you know that $2b+5a=10$.  Solving for $a$ yields the area as
$$A=\frac{1}{2}b\left(2-\frac{2}{5}b\right)$$
for which you can take the derivative and set equal to zero.

Answer (score 0):

A line through $(2,5)$ having slope $m$ must satisfy
$$ (y-5)=m(x-2)$$
so the intercepts are :
$$ x_{int} = -\frac 5m +2 \text{ and } y_{int}=-2m+5$$
The function to be minimized is :
$$A(m)=\frac 12( -\frac 5m +2)(-2m+5)$$